# Trimmed seatpost gets stuck without bottoming out

Tags: seatpost, seattube

I have a new-to-me bike that I can comfortably standover, but I just cannot get the seat down as low as I need. Thinking I'd just need to trim the seatpost, I took it to my bike shop and they did it for me.

After getting it back, it's certainly coming nowhere close to the bottle cage screws, yet I can feel the seatpost getting tighter as I push it down, and eventually would have to really force it.

Are seatposts built with a taper so that this would be happening? Would buying a shorter seatpost be the solution, or is there something potentially wrong with my frame?

Comment: More detail would help - frame manufacturer and model, along with seat post length and how far in the seat post is when it binds.  Maybe all that is needed is cut the post down more.

Comment: How far can you insert it? Maybe the seatpost is too wide? Or maybe there is some corrosion or even paint stuck to the inside? Seatposts come in 0.2mm diameter increments, it’s conceivable that the seattube is just wide enough around the clamp area (where the slit is) to allow a slightly too wide seatpost to be inserted for the first 5 centimeters or so.

Comment: Just a note, if a seatpost is shortened, the line on the seatpost marking the minimum insertion height does not apply anymore as it has moved up the post the amount that has been trimmed/cut off.

Comment: Requires close examination.  The post may curve slightly.  It may bulge near the top.  You may be running into the shaping of the post near the top to allow it to fasten to the seat.

Answer (score 4):

How far in it's going before it begins to get tight is a major piece of the puzzle here.

If it's not going in much past the seat cluster area, it's possible the seatpost is a size too big, but the top of the bore is either a sloppy fit or has been manipulated to take the larger size.

If it goes part way into the seat tube and feels normal up to a point, but then tightens up and stops out of nowhere, that suggests either the seatpost (likely) or seat tube are distorted. Test by holding a straight edge against each.

A seatpost getting bent and causing this sort of problem is not unheard of, albeit not common.

Seatposts are not made tapered.

Comment: It's also possible the post is the right size, the top of the tube is a little loose, and the cut has left a burr that's binding